# Elasticsearch : get compliment of output

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to get set of result which is outside the provided filters.
Example :

```
Query : document_id and filter
{
   Document_id : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
},
{
   Query Result : 1,2,3,4,5,6
}
```

Output : 7

I can perform the above manipulation in java code as well but I want to get this result from Query. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your filter in a `must_not` clause inside a `bool` query, like this:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : [
        <YOUR FILTER QUERIES HERE>
      ]
    }
  }
}
```